# Eliminar .form para que no se quede

Tags: java

Hola buenas tengo una aplicacion en java que tiene un `main` y desde este llama a una interfaz que esta echa con un `.form` y un `.class` una vez la creo quiero con un boton acceder a otra pantalla y que esta se elimine pero no lo consigo algun consejo lo que tengo hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("UI");
                        frame.setContentPane(new UI().mainPanel);
                        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        frame.pack();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                        panel.setVisible(false);
```

he probado con dispose y tampoco me funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Berky espero te sirva este ejemplo:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame parent = new JFrame();
        parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        parent.setSize(300,300);
        parent.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        parent.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JFrame child = new JFrame();
        child.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        child.setSize(300,300);
        child.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        child.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("child window");
        child.add(label);





        JButton button = new JButton("open child window");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                child.setVisible(true);
                parent.dispose();
            }
        });

        parent.add(button);
        parent.setVisible(true);
        parent.pack();

    }

}
```

Comment: una pregunta y si los formularios se abren desde clases diferentes, uno en el main y el otro en otra clase, como haría para borrar el primero?

Comment: Les puedes pasar la referencia de una clase a otra  por el constructor y seguria funcionando, si no me he explicado bien hazmelo saber para poner algun ejemplo.